# Show part of next item in TabView

Tags: swiftui

I want to show part of next item in tabview as following design

[image]

I managed to show one item per page but I couldn't show part of next one. Here's my code

```
GeometryReader { proxy in
    TabView(selection: $viewModel.selectedTabIndex) {
        ForEach(self.viewModel.data?.perspective ?? []) { item in
            HStack(spacing: 20) {
                Image("icon")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .frame(width: 24, height: 24, alignment: .center)
                Text(item.name)
                    .font(.system(size: 16, weight: .medium))
                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                    .tag(item.id)
                Spacer()
            }
            .frame(width: proxy.size.width - 70, height: 40, alignment: .center)
            .padding(.horizontal)
            .background(.red)
            .cornerRadius(5)
        }
    }
    .tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .never))
}
.frame(height: 40, alignment: .center)
```

Comment: What is the whole tab UI supposed to look like? Is it just what you have shown, or is there a whole page underneath?

Comment: @Yrb it's only what I showed

Comment: @DotFreelancer Did you find any solution to show the next item in tabview partially?